# i am not successful. I am trying to get my slideshow appear on my local server

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, express-handlebars

everything loads but the slideshow is not working on my homepage. I've got a /lib/slide.js file im trying to place on my homepage. Images are referenced and working. I just cant get to get them to appear on the page

this is slide.js

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    var slideIndex = 0;
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    return slides;
};
```

this is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
var slides = require('./lib/slides.js');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var app = express();

app.use('/slides', slides);
//form encoding
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//app port for viewing
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
//Home page route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', { slides });
});
```

this is the html file

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="img/palmTree.jpg" style="width:100%; height:35%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="img/00.jpg" style="width:100%; height:35%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="img/01.jpg" style="width:100%; height:35%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way of serving static files like css and javascript

make a "public" folder in root dir of your project and also put

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

in your index.js file

now you can put your static files in that public folder and link them with html
like following:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/slide.js">
```

well i can see you are trying to access slide.js in your app frontend.
but you can't send a controller function to frontend.
you can actually put your code on github and share a link here.

Comment: thats not what I am trying to do. That's all in place.

Comment: you can only pass variables to handlebars not functions and controllers.